# What's the best way to create a replication/load balancing module?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

We have a sharepoint doucment library, the site consist media files(like images, word document, .psd file) and then we have a local CME (Alterian) which can be integrated to the SharePoint library in order to share the document library but the site needs to be on http// not an https//, coincidentally current sharepoint site is on https//, so we need to figure out a way/write a module which will work as a scheduled job (possibly using SPJobDefination class) and check on https// site for recently modified/added or deleted documents/records and then will copy them/normalize them to a dev site (hosted on http//, replica of the production https// site).

Experts please share your view's to proceed with a best approach to make this happen. (At an initial stage I'll have to copy over all the existing meta-data from the current https// site aswell)

Thanks a lot in advance for the time.

Answer (score 0):

I would use event handlers on the `https` document library. Please see the [SPItemEventReceiver.ItemAdded Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spitemeventreceiver.itemadded%28v=office.14%29.aspx) and [SPItemEventReceiver.ItemUpdated Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spitemeventreceiver.itemupdated%28v=office.14%29.aspx).

So, every time you will add or modify an item, the code inside the methods is triggered. Inside the code, you may take the library document and copy it to the `http` site.

Regarding the existing items, you could write a simple console application which will copy the items from one list to the other.

Make sure that you make use of the [SPListItem.SystemUpdate Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.splistitem.systemupdate.aspx).

Also, the following excerpt from an answer to the question [Moving Documents from library to library deletes version history, how do you retain it?](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sharepointgeneral/thread/6b00f715-b1ff-48c9-8157-0f535c9464a2) could be helpful for starting:

> (...) We can get the “SPFile” and the “SPFileVersion” objects from the
>   original library and add them to another library one by one. After
>   copying a file or version, get the original custom property form the
>   source file or version and use the “SPListItem.SystemUpdate(false)”
>   method to update the target file or version. This workaround can
>   persist most of the properties except the “modified time” or “modified
>   by” field. (...)

Comment: If I understood correctly, what you are saying is : instead of pulling from https//, push from https// to http// site, and in the starting just replicate the site, by writing a one time replication module, correct ? I'll definitely start digging with this approach, I am new to sharepoint development, have experience wuth c#. Thanks for considration, let me give it a try and I shall bug you for further help :)